# In portrait mode my iPad's RootViewController table has a blank first row, if row at all

Tags: uitableview

I fill two NSArrays with static text from two plist files.  These are titles and subtitles for the very first UITableView using RootViewController. In landscape the table is aligned to the top without a blank row or empty space. The table displays fine.

In the portrait mode,the table displays but there is blank space at about the thickness or height of a single table row.  I've debugged and both arrays have a count of 5.  There is blank space (seems to be exactly a row high) and 5 cells in the display.  If I navigate by selecting an item and come back, the space is gone.

Here's my RootViewController.

```
    //
//  RootViewController.m
//  Punch
//
//  Created by David Whitehurst on 1/27/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "ContextController.h"
#import "PunchAppDelegate.h"


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize contextController,detailViewController,arrayData,subArrayData,imagesList;

- (void)configureView {
}

- (NSArray *) getImageArray {

    NSString *goalPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"85-trophy@2x" ofType:@"png"];
    NSString *vitalPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"77-ekg@2x" ofType:@"png"];
    NSString *medicinePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"79-medical-bag@2x" ofType:@"png"];
    NSString *mealPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"48-fork-and-knife@2x" ofType:@"png"];
    NSString *exercisePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"63-runner@2x" ofType:@"png"];

    UIImage *goalPathRes = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:goalPath];
    UIImage *vitalPathRes = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:vitalPath];
    UIImage *medicinePathRes = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:medicinePath];
    UIImage *mealPathRes = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:mealPath];
    UIImage *exercisePathRes = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:exercisePath];

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:goalPathRes,vitalPathRes,medicinePathRes,mealPathRes,exercisePathRes,nil];

    return array;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *dataFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"array" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSString *dataFileSub = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"subarray" ofType:@"plist"];

    imagesList = [self getImageArray];  

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataFile]) {
        arrayData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataFile];
    } 

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataFileSub]) {
        subArrayData = [[NSArray alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:dataFileSub];
    } 

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    self.title = @"Punch";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    //self.tableView
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // set first row selected
    NSIndexPath *ip=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];

}
/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.arrayData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [subArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [imagesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // The table view should not be re-orderable.
    return NO;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    contextController = [[ContextController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContextController" bundle:nil];
    PunchAppDelegate *delegate = (PunchAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (0 == indexPath.row) {
        [delegate setContextKey:@"Goal"];
        [self.contextController setKey:@"Goal"];
        self.contextController.title = @"Goals";
    }

    if (1 == indexPath.row) {
        [delegate setContextKey:@"Food"];
        [self.contextController setKey:@"Food"];
        self.contextController.title = @"Food Log";
    }

    if (2 == indexPath.row) {
        [delegate setContextKey:@"Blood"];
        [self.contextController setKey:@"Blood"];
        self.contextController.title = @"Blood Sugar Log";
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contextController animated:YES];
    [contextController release];    

}

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
         // Custom initialization.
     }
     return self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [contextController release];
    [arrayData release];
    [subArrayData release];
    [imagesList release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Please help with any suggestions on how to get rid of this blank space or why it might be happening.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. It was the translucent YES property.  I changed it to NO first and it aligned properly at the top.  Then I commented what I assume were default properties.

```
    //self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    //self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: BarStyle and tintColor were however needed because in landscape the nav bar was grey. I uncommented those properties.